# "Borrowed value does not live long enough", dropped when used in a loop

Tags: string, loops, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I understand that the `String` is dropped when the scope of the `loop` ends and that the vector `input` contains slices of `trimmed_text`.

I suppose the resolution is to move the ownership of those slices to `input` or something like that. How can this be done?

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input: Vec<&str>;

    loop {
        let mut input_text = String::new();
        println!("Type instruction in the format Add <name> to <department>:");
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input_text)
            .expect("failed to read from stdin");
        let trimmed_text: String = input_text.trim().to_string();

        input = trimmed_text.split(" ").collect();

        if input[0] == "Add" && input[2] == "to" {
            break;
        } else {
            println!("Invalid format.");
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

The compile error:

```
error[E0597]: `trimmed_text` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:17
   |
14 |         input = trimmed_text.split(" ").collect();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
21 |     }
   |     - `trimmed_text` dropped here while still borrowed
22 | 
23 |     println!("{:?}", input);
   |                      ----- borrow later used here
```

Comment: I think simply changing your `input` from holding `&str` to owned strings would do it. You might also need to explicitly copy the trimmed and split text into `input`

Comment: In addition to changing the type, you need to explicitly turn the string slice into strings, e.g. using `.map(String::from)` or similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.split()` returns references to a `String` which is dropped by the end of the loop, but you want `input` to live past the end of the loop, so you should refactor it to hold owned values instead of references. Example:

```rust
use std::io;

fn example() {
    let mut input: Vec<String>; // changed from &str to String

    loop {
        let mut input_text = String::new();
        println!("Type instruction in the format Add <name> to <department>:");
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input_text)
            .expect("failed to read from stdin");

        // map str refs into owned Strings
        input = input_text.trim().split(" ").map(String::from).collect();

        if input[0] == "Add" && input[2] == "to" {
            break;
        } else {
            println!("Invalid format.");
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7f5fad1b0ed2835ca9db65558460837)

Comment: Correction. `.split()` returns references to a `str`. Not `String`.

Answer (score 1):

As you did understand, the problem is that the owner of the slices doesn't live long enough. What you didn't point out (and maybe did not explicitly see) is that the owner is the variable `trimmed_text`. So what you want to do (if you don't want to copy each slice to have better performances) is to make  `trimmed_text`'s scope bigger:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input: Vec<&str>;
    let mut trimmed_text: String;

    loop {
        ...
        trimmed_text = input_text.trim().to_string();

        input = trimmed_text.split(" ").collect();

        if input[0] == "Add" && input[2] == "to" {
            break;
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

Here, we resolved the error of the lifetime of the owner of the slices. However, we have a second issue:

```rust
13 |         trimmed_text = input_text.trim().to_string();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `trimmed_text` occurs here
14 | 
15 |         input = trimmed_text.split(" ").collect();
   |         -----   ------------ borrow of `trimmed_text` occurs here
   |         |
   |         borrow might be used here, when `input` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `std::vec::Vec`
```

This tells us that after a loop, the `input` variable still borrows `trimmed_text` as it is modified. To fix this, we can reduce the scope of input so that input's scope doesn't contain the line 13 :

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    // Remove the "let mut input: Vec<&str>;"
    let mut trimmed_text: String;

    loop {
        ...
        trimmed_text = input_text.trim().to_string();

        let input: Vec<&str> = trimmed_text.split(" ").collect();

        ...
    }
}
```

If we don't use `input` outside of the loop, this works just fine. Now we just need to output the value of `input` at the end of the loop :

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    // Remove the "let mut input: Vec<&str>;"
    let mut trimmed_text: String;

    let results = loop {
        ...
        trimmed_text = input_text.trim().to_string();

        let input: Vec<&str> = trimmed_text.split(" ").collect();

        if input[0] == "Add" && input[2] == "to" {
            break input;
        }
        ...
    };

    println!("{:?}", results);
}
```

And here we have it !

## TL;DR:

Here is a code that does what you want without duplicating the slices :

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut trimmed_text: String;

    let results = loop {
        let mut input_text = String::new();
        println!("Type instruction in the format Add <name> to <department>:");
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input_text)
            .expect("failed to read from stdin");
        trimmed_text = input_text.trim().to_string();

        let input: Vec<&str> = trimmed_text.split(" ").collect();

        if input[0] == "Add" && input[2] == "to" {
            break input;
        } else {
            println!("Invalid format.");
        }
    };

    println!("{:?}", results);
}
```

I renamed `input` to `results` to avoid confusion with the `input` variable inside the loop. Feel free to rename it back to `input` if you really want to.