# How to return result of split() back to main() in rust?

Tags: rust

I want to read a csv file, when I use simple static array to simulate, it compiled OK.
But if I changed it to real read file code, it compiled failed

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn read_csv(guess_number: &mut BTreeMap<&str, &str>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // let lines = ["Tom,4", "John,6"];
    // for line in lines.iter() {
    let file = File::open("sample.csv")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    for (_idx, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
        if let Ok(line) = line {
            let split = line.split(",");
            let vec: Vec<_> = split.collect();
            println!("{} {:?}", line, vec);
            //let number: i32 = vec[1].trim().parse().unwrap();
            // guess_number.insert(vec[0], number);
            guess_number.insert(vec[0], vec[1]);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
fn main() {
    let mut guess_number: BTreeMap<&str, &str> = BTreeMap::new();
    read_csv(&mut guess_number);
    for (k, v) in guess_number {
        println!("{} {:?}", k, v);
    }
}
```

The compile error message

```
   Compiling sample v0.1.0 (/home/hosthome/prj/rs/sample)
error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:25
   |
6  | fn read_csv(guess_number: &mut BTreeMap<&str, &str>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
   |                                               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
13 |             let split = line.split(",");
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
18 |             guess_number.insert(vec[0], vec[1]);
   |             ----------------------------------- argument requires that `line` is borrowed for `'1`
19 |         }
   |         - `line` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `sample` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve it.

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn read_csv(guess_number: &mut BTreeMap<String, String>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = File::open("sample.csv")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    // read file line by line split line by "," and insert into guess_number
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        let split = line.split(",").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        guess_number.insert(split[0].to_owned(), split[1].to_owned());
    }
    Ok(())
}
fn main() {
    let mut guess_number: BTreeMap<String, String> = BTreeMap::new();
    read_csv(&mut guess_number);
    for (k, v) in guess_number {
        println!("{} {:?}", k, v);
    }
}
```

I changed the BTreeMap to holding owned String so that strings created inside a function don't have to be borrowed.

And the `split` returns references to a `String` which is dropped by the end of the loop, so I turn them into `String` before the drop (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162034/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-dropped-when-used-in-a-loop))